# Unable to get bcrypt.compare() to work, keeps returning false when should be true

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, jestjs, bcrypt

**Problem:**

I am unable to get `bcrypt.compare(plainText, hashedPassword)` to return `true` when the plain text password is the same as the ones used to create the hashed password during testing.

**Background:**

- I'm using Mongodb, Express, NodeJS, Jest, and Supertest in my project.
- I haven't tried to see if I get the same issue with postman yet, as I'm trying to get more practice with using Jest.
- The user created in the beforeEach function in *user.test.ts* appears in the database and the hashedpassword in the database matches the one that I console.log in controller.ts file.
- I somehow managed to get it to pass the test one time and when i removed the console.logs, that were used to check what the password and hashedpasswords were, it went back to returning the same error :(

**Error from test:**

```
 FAIL  src/components/users/users.test.ts (6.73 s)
  User registration
    ✓ Should create a new user (1985 ms)
    ✓ Should return 400 if user exists (152 ms)
  User login
    ✕ Should login an existing user with valid credentials and return accessToken (215 ms)

  ● User login › Should login an existing user with valid credentials and return accessToken

    expected 200 "OK", got 400 "Bad Request"

      63 |             .post('/user/login')
      64 |             .send(existingUserLogin)
    > 65 |             .expect(200);
         |              ^
      66 |         expect(response.body).toMatchObject({
      67 |             accessToken: expect.any(String)
      68 |         });

      at src/components/users/users.test.ts:65:14
      at src/components/users/users.test.ts:8:71
      at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (src/components/users/users.test.ts:4:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/users/users.test.ts:61:98)
      ----
      at Test._assertStatus (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:252:14)
      at node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:308:13
      at Test._assertFunction (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:285:13)
      at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:164:23)
      at Server.localAssert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:120:14)
```

**Code:**

*users.test.ts*

```
import request from 'supertest';
import app from '../../server';
import User from './model';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

const existingUser = {
    firstName: 'Thomas',
    lastName: 'Hatek',
    email: 'thomashatek@gmail.com',
    password: '1234567aA'
};
const existingUserLogin = {
    email: 'thomashatek@gmail.com',
    password: '1234567aA'
};
const nonExistingUser = {
    firstName: 'Rod',
    lastName: 'Chainmic',
    email: 'rodchainmic@gmail.com',
    password: '123456aA',
    confirmPassword: '123456aA'
};

beforeEach(async () => {
    await User.deleteMany();
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(existingUser.password, salt);
    existingUser.password = hashedPassword;
    await User.create(existingUser);
});

describe('User registration', () => {
    it('Should create a new user', async () => {
        const response = await request(app)
            .post('/user/register')
            .send(nonExistingUser)
            .expect(201);
        expect(response.body).toMatchObject({
            __v: 0,
            _id: expect.any(String),
            firstName: expect.any(String),
            lastName: expect.any(String),
            email: expect.any(String),
            token: expect.any(String),
            createdAt: expect.any(String),
            updatedAt: expect.any(String)
        });
    });
    it('Should return 400 if user exists', async () => {
        return request(app)
            .post('/user/register')
            .send(existingUser)
            .expect(400);
    });
});
describe('User login', () => {
    it('Should login an existing user with valid credentials and return accessToken', async () => {
        const response = await request(app)
            .post('/user/login')
            .send(existingUserLogin)
            .expect(200);
        expect(response.body).toMatchObject({
            accessToken: expect.any(String)
        });
    });
    
});
```

*controller.ts*:

```
export const loginUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (user) {
            console.log(password, user.password) \\1234567aA $2b$10$aYKxhy8dlN9K8t.GKy7GgetmKAM1LX5zXwSSyvjNmgpk/44HlbH8K
            const passwordValidation = await bcrypt.compare(
                password,
                user.password
            );
            
            //Invalid credentials, this is where the test encounters the 400 bad request
            if (!passwordValidation) {
                const error = new AppError({
                    httpCode: HttpCode.BAD_REQUEST,
                    description: 'Invalid Credentials'
                });
                logger.error(error);
                errorHandler.handleError(error, res);
            }
            const accessToken = generateToken(user.id);
            res.status(200).json({ accessToken });
        } else {
            const error = new AppError({
                httpCode: HttpCode.BAD_REQUEST,
                description: 'User does not exist'
            });
            logger.error(error);
            errorHandler.handleError(error, res);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof Error) {
            logger.error(error);
            errorHandler.handleError(error, res);
        } else {
            const unknownError = new Error(
                'Unknown error occuring at loginUser controller'
            );
            logger.error(unknownError);
            errorHandler.handleError(unknownError, res);
        }
    }
};
```

*model.ts*

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        firstName: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        lastName: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        avatar: {
            required: false,
            type: String
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
export default User
```

**What I tried so far:**

- Switch the arguments of the bcrypt.compare from `bcrypt.compare(plainText, hashedPassword)` to `bcrypt.compare(hashedPassword, plainText)`
- Rebuilding with tsc
- Using a different password than the one shown above
- Running `npm install` again
- Restarting VScode
- Doing `bcrypt.compare(password.trim(), hashedPassword.trim())`

I feel I'm missing something really simple but I can't seem to find it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, in the `beforeEach` function in `users.test.ts`, when I was hashing the password it was changing the `existingUser`'s password. So when it reached the third test, the one that failed, it was hashing an already hashedpassword instead of 1234567aA.

So I did the following and it worked:

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
    await User.deleteMany();
    //created a new variable to prevent the existingUser object from being altered
    const newUser = {...existingUser}
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(existingUser.password, salt);
    newUser.password = hashedPassword;
    await User.create(newUser);
});
```